# Typeahead result population returns the entire array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, typeahead.js

I'm using the twitter typeahead javascript library to pre-populate a search term to help the users searching for specific names. I'm using their example `substringMatcher` function which can be found [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).

I'm populating my data using an Ajax call which returns the data I expect. This array is then passed to that example `substringMatcher` function however when searching it returns the entire array instead of each individual item (see image).

It should just return the individual name, not the array!

[image]

Here he is my typeahead function & source;

```
$('input#practition-typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 3,
},{
    name: 'output',
    source: substringMatcher(
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                action: 'get_all_practitioners'
            },
            success:function(output){       
                return output;
            }
        })
    )
});
```

My substring matcher function

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;
    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];
    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });
    cb(matches);
  }; 
};
```

**Edit -** 
When I `console.log` my `output` from the `success` of my ajax I get the following;

```
success:function(output){
    console.log(output);        
    return output;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ajax calls are asynchronous you should not return the values from the "success" function of ajax calls. Instead you can use promise to monitor the completion of Ajax call and then use "then" method of promise to do further work.

Comment: Please provide your ajax call output. As per `substringMatcher` documentation, it needs array of string.

Comment: @Sagar Thank you, updated with the result set from the ajax call

Comment: Then no problem for data format. Consider @RK_15 comment.

Comment: @RK_15 Thank you, I've just hardcoded an array variable and the result output does work as expected! Could you explain further your recommendation please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by just delaying my typeahead instance until the ajax call is complete. The full code can be found below;

```
var output = [];
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        action: 'get_all_practitioners'
    },
    success:function(output){
        console.log(output);        
        return output;
    }
}).done(function(output){
    $('input#practition-typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1,
    },{
        name: 'output',
        source: substringMatcher(
            output
        )
    }); 
});
```